# rails not receive array value strong parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters

I had a problem that it didn't received `array value` when i tried to submit `array value` which i used `checkbox`.

Here is my code:

This is `migration` file:

```
create_table :users do |t|
  t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
  t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""
  t.text :receive_mail, array: true, default: []
  ...
```

This is `function` which i put `array attributes`:

```
def configure_sign_up_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [
    :address,
    {receive_mail: []}
  ])
end
```

This is `view` file:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:receive_mail, [[0, "receive new article"], [1, "receive new ebook"]], :first, :last, include_hidden: false) do |b| %>
    <%= b.label {b.check_box + b.text} %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

When i submit, i checked `params` and it had a value as `"receive_mail"=>["0", "1"]`, but when i checked when it `permited`, it always return `"receive_mail"=>[]`.

I didn't understand why it didn't receive value.

Any help would be great appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue stems from your use of the `keys` option, which appears to only accept a list of symbols. You could try using:

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [
  :address,
  :receive_mail
])
```

However, I think you'll run into the following issue, mentioned in the [Devise docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters):

> If you have some checkboxes that express the roles a user may take on registration, the browser will send those selected checkboxes as an array. An array is not one of Strong Parameters' permitted scalars, so we need to configure Devise in the following way ...

Given that, here's a variant of your code based on the example from the docs that *might* work:

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |user_params|
  user_params.permit({receive_mail: []}, :address)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried it, but it didn't work.